# how can I set an horizontal space before the units using the siunitx package in math mode?

Tags: spacing, siunitx

I often use the `\si[]{}` command from the `siunitx` package in math mode to avoid formatting the units using `\mathrm{}` and superscripts, however when doing this there is no space displayed at all between the numbers and the units, it looks weird.

for example:

```
\(\mathrm{m}=1 \si{\kilo\gram}\)
```

I can overcome this in inline math mode doing this:

```
\(\mathrm{m}=1\) \si{\kilo\gram}
```

But I can´t do this most math environments.

Note that there is a white space between units when you use two or more of them

```
\(\mathrm{k}=40\) \si{\newton\per\meter}
```

I would like to add a white space between the numbers and the units similarly to the one between Newton and metre when using the `\si[]{}` command in math mode.

How can that be done?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
    Some math in inline mode \(\mathrm{m}=1\) \si{\kilo\gram}, and some centered math:
    \[\mathrm{k}=40 \si{\newton\per\meter}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `\SI{1}{\kilo\gram}`?

Comment: There is this example in the documentation \SI[mode=text]{1.23}{J.mol^{-1}.K^{-1}} and I still see the J very close to the 1.23, is that because of the mode=text option?

Comment: The space looks okay to me, but if you want a larger one it can be configured, see the documentation.

Comment: @PaulLara - The outputs of `\SI[mode=text]{1.23}{J.mol^{-1}.K^{-1}}` and `\SI{1.23}{J.mol^{-1}.K^{-1}}` differ only if text-mode and math-mode numerals differ. (The user guide of the `siunitx` package uses oldstyle numerals in text mode.)  The `mode=text` option does *not* influence the space between the numeric and units parts of `\SI`. Speaking for myself, I prefer the form `\SI{1.23}{\joule\per\mole\per\kelvin}`, both because I find it to be easier to parse and because its output can be reconfigured "on the fly", with options such as `per-mode=symbol` and `per-mode=fraction`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your method of keeping the number and units separate, you would need to add the desired space explicitly. Using the `\SI{}{}` command, you can adjust this by changing the value of `number-unit-product` using `\sisetup`. See table 24 in the documentation.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
    Some math in inline mode \(\mathrm{m}=\SI{1}{\kilo\gram}\), and some centered math:
    \[\mathrm{k}=\SI{40}{\newton\per\meter}\]

\sisetup{number-unit-product=\ }
    Some math in inline mode \(\mathrm{m}=\SI{1}{\kilo\gram}\), and some centered math:
    \[\mathrm{k}=\SI{40}{\newton\per\meter}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]